# ActiveMQ message redelivery delay not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I have configured an ActiveMQ message queue with transactions in a Spring Boot application.
Here is my beans configuration:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                             @Qualifier("jmsTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                                             JmsErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    return factory;
}


@Bean
public RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy() {
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(20000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(20000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveryDelay(20000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
    redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(-1);
    redeliveryPolicy.setDestination(defaultDestination());
    return redeliveryPolicy;
}


@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(getAddress());
    connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy());
    return connectionFactory;
}


@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector(getAddress());
    PersistenceAdapter persistenceAdapter = new KahaDBPersistenceAdapter();
    persistenceAdapter.setDirectory(new File(...));
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(persistenceAdapter);
    broker.setBrokerName(getName());
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    broker.setDataDirectoryFile(new File(...));
    broker.setSchedulerSupport(true);
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    return broker;
}


@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
    jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(defaultDestination());
    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(false);
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Although maximum redeliveries attribute is working as expected (unlimited) the delay setting is not, which is strange.
Any tips on what might be the issue?

---

**EDIT**

I found that the issue disappears when I comment out this:

```
factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
```

from jmsListenerFactory. I am not sure if I understand the reason though and if it is safe to completely remove it.

Comment: Had the same issue, removing transaction manager helped